# How to built AND condition between should and must elastic search bool query

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Here is the sample USER document

```
{
  "id" : "1234567",
  "userId" : "testuser01",
  "firstName" : "firstname",
  "lastName" : "lastname",
  "orgId" : "567890",
  "phoneNumber" : "1234567890"
}
```

I want to build a search query where in I want to pull all those users which belong to particular **orgId** AND which matches the search text entered by user in any of the fields (userId, firstname, etc.)

ex. if search is made using text "**first**", I want to pull all those records which belong to particular orgId AND fields containing **first** in it.

Sample query I am trying is

```
    "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "term" : {
            "orgId.keyword" : {
              "value" : "567890",
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should" : [
        {
          "simple_query_string" : {
            "query" : "first*",
            "fields" : [
              "lastName^1.0"
            ],
            "flags" : -1,
            "default_operator" : "or",
            "lenient" : false,
            "analyze_wildcard" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string" : {
            "query" : "first*",
            "fields" : [
              "userId^1.0"
            ],
            "flags" : -1,
            "default_operator" : "or",
            "lenient" : false,
            "analyze_wildcard" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string" : {
            "query" : "first*",
            "fields" : [
              "orgId^1.0"
            ],
            "flags" : -1,
            "default_operator" : "or",
            "lenient" : false,
            "analyze_wildcard" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string" : {
            "query" : "first*",
            "fields" : [
              "firstName^1.0"
            ],
            "flags" : -1,
            "default_operator" : "or",
            "lenient" : false,
            "analyze_wildcard" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string" : {
            "query" : "first*",
            "fields" : [
              "phoneNumber^1.0"
            ],
            "flags" : -1,
            "default_operator" : "or",
            "lenient" : false,
            "analyze_wildcard" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string" : {
            "query" : "first*",
            "fields" : [
              "id^1.0"
            ],
            "flags" : -1,
            "default_operator" : "or",
            "lenient" : false,
            "analyze_wildcard" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      ],
      "disable_coord" : false,
      "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  },
  "sort" : [
    {
      "userId.keyword" : {
        "order" : "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Issue I am facing is, I want to have AND condition between MUST and SHOULD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify the query for each field in `query_string` query. Rather you can specify the list of fields as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "orgId.keyword": {
              "value": "567890",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "first*",
            "fields": [
              "lastName^1.0",
              "userId^1.0",
              "orgId^1.0",
              "firstName^1.0",
              "phoneNumber^1.0",
              "id^1.0"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "userId.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Also to answer

> How to built AND condition between should and must elastic search bool query?

here is a sample query for this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field1": "someval"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "field2": [
                    "v1",
                    "v2"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "this AND that OR thus"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. We are using Elastic version 5.5 and I don't see option to specify multiple fileds for simple_query_string.  Any suggestions ?

Comment: It does takes list of fields. Take a look at the documentation of es 5.5 [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-simple-query-string-query).

Comment: Thank you. I am able to use multiple fields now.

Comment: One more question, see my elastic document has multiple field, if I want to search document based on multiple fields with AND condition then what is the simplest query ? Do I need multiple nested bool query with must ?

Comment: Go through [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#simple-query-string-top-level-params) documentation to get the understanding of operator.